# Find out minimum interval milliseconds

Tags: function, internet-explorer

I´ve programmed a intervall-function with 70ms. The problem is that IE says he hasn´t enough memory. In another case it asked me with a dialog to exit the script because the script on the page is causing Internet Explorer to run slow.

So how can I find out the milliseconds so that the error no longer appears?

Cheers

```
// EDIT: CODE:
var chkInterval = setTimeout(function(){
 // CHECK some things
 // ...
 // repeat call
 setTimeout(arguments.callee, 70);
});
```

Comment: I have converted my setInterval-function to a loop of setTimout-functions. But that didn´t solved the problem. IE8 + IE9 still say that there is not enough memory. I don´t know what causing this problem

Comment: Post your code so we can try to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: ... done! Give it a look above

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, argument.callee is deprecated and is not guaranteed to work in IE. Your problem might be caused because you're using argument.callee. Here's a slightly better way of doing this:

```
function chkInterval() {
    // CHECK some things
    // ...
    // repeat call
    setTimeout(chkInterval, 70);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I´ve done it this way but the dialog that the script is causing internet explorer to run slow appears 
nevertheless...